# Does a Pipeline object store the score of the data it trained with?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, model, pipeline

I was wondering if a saved model in a Pipeline object contains the score of the data with which it has been trained. If so, how to get that score without having to put the data back in?

Comment: It does not; no stored model object includes such information. You would need to save separately, say, the cross validation results in order to keep that information. If you have not done so beforehand, there is no way you can get this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the model.  Mostly, no.  Also, you'd need to specify what exactly you mean by "score"; there are many metrics that might be saved somewhere.

`kNN` models store the training data in a private attribute `_fit_X` ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca126bcb2c0ad813226963621cafe38adb/sklearn/neighbors/_base.py#L468)), so you could recreate a score from that (though you're not really saving much work here).

`HistGradientBoosting` models store an iteration-wise training and validation score ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier.html)).  `GradientBoosting` models similarly save loss functions at each iteration.

Cross-validation models like `LogisticRegressionCV` save the cross-validation scores for each hyperparameter value.  Those are significantly different from a training score though.